# Property "UserIdentity._id" is not defined

Tags: php, yii

Keeps saying property is not defined how ever it should be defined code and stack trace are below. I am using Yii framework for this project. The stack trace says I am receiving the correct user ID as well.

```
$users= Users::model()->findByAttributes(array('Email'=>$this->Email));
        
        if($users===null) {
            $this->errorCode = self::ERROR_USERNAME_INVALID; 
            echo 'failed here1';
        }
        else if(!$users->validatePassword($this->Password)) {
            $this->errorCode = self::ERROR_PASSWORD_INVALID;
            echo 'failed here 2';
        }
        else {           
            $this->errorCode = self::ERROR_NONE;
            $this->_id = $users->UserID; //this is the error line
        }
        return !$this->errorCode;
    }
    
    public function getId() {
        return $this->_id;
    }

}
```

Stack trace

## 0

- C:\xampp\htdocs\barbadosv2\protected\components\UserIdentity.php(48): CComponent->__set("_id", "51")

Comment: Are you extending CUserIdentity and do you have a private property `_id` in your `UserIdentity`? Seems you have not.

Comment: Yea I was extending CUserIdentity and I had forgot to add the property, rookie mistake Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to define the `_id` property inside the UserIdentity class. (So outside any functions)

```
class UserIdentity extends CUserIdentity {
    private $_id;

     // .. any functions etc.
}
```